# source.vue doesn't work in my vue snippet in sublime text3?

Tags: vue.js, sublimetext3, sublimetext-snippet

I have a very annoying problem with my sublime snippet about .vue type flie.
Say I want to add a vue snippet in sublime on my own, and I want the vue tabtrigger below works in vue type file only.
I add these codes into my `vue.sublime-snippet`:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
        Some text
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>vue</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.vue</scope>
</snippet>
```

After saving this file in my sublime folder, I create a `test.vue` file and type `vue` and then press Tab.
But nothing happened. What I expected is `Some text` could appear after tabbing in `test.vue` file.
Why doesn't  my snippet work on vue file?

PS: I changed `source.vue` into `source.js` `source.php`,etc in my snippet and tested in corresponding js, php file, they all work fine. Only vue didn't work out. Is there anything wrong with sublime identifying vue type file? How to  solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

The correct scope selector to use for Vue.js is `text.html.vue`, which can be seen by creating a new, empty tab in ST, setting the syntax to Vue.js and then going to the Tools menu -> Developer -> Show Scope Name or by checking the syntax definition: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-syntax-highlight/blob/f87459fc1bf26a4b8e50e232757d4682892c971d/vue.tmLanguage#L1465-L1466

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue and I used `source.js` as the scope selector.

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
    your snippet here
 ]]></content>
   <tabTrigger>vue</tabTrigger>
   <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
   <scope>source.js</scope>
 </snippet>
```